# How to directly update WooCommerce product stock quantity by its sku

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

A have a ton of variable products. I'm using cron to run the script every X minutes for fetching stock level from an external source. If I use `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` and `update_post_meta` it takes too long so I'm trying to find the way to use a custom prepared query.
If I know `product_id` query would be like that:

```
$conn->prepare( "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=? WHERE post_id=? AND meta_key=`_stock`" );
```

But I only know a product SKU. So how to modify this query to update `_stock` based on a product SKU?

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | _sku | ABCD |
| 10 | _stock | 25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$wpdb` and `JOIN` works too slow, so the fastest way is to use four separate prepared queries:

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect( $conn, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );

// Get product ID by SKU
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = ?");

// Update stock level on postmeta table
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value = ? WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND post_id = ?");

// Update stock data on wc_product_meta_lookup table
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_meta_lookup SET stock_quantity = ?, stock_status = ? WHERE product_id = ?");

// Update stock status on postmeta table
$stmt4 = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta SET meta_value = ? WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status' AND post_id = ?");

foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $qty        = $product['ON_HAND'];
    $sku        = $product['PRODUCT_SKU'];
    $status     = $qty ? 'instock' : 'onbackorder';

    // Get product ID by SKU
    $stmt1->bind_param( "s", $sku );
    $stmt1->execute();

    $res = $stmt1->get_result();
            
    while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {

        $id = $row['post_id'];

        // Update stock level on postmeta table
        $stmt2->bind_param( "dd", $qty, $id );
        $stmt2->execute();

        // Update stock data on wc_product_meta_lookup table
        $stmt3->bind_param( "dsd", $qty, $status, $id );
        $stmt3->execute();

        // Update stock status on postmeta table
        $stmt4->bind_param( "sd", $status, $id );
        $stmt4->execute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL query embedded in a function that will update product stock quantity based on the product SKU *(the table `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` needs also to be updated)*:

```
/*
 * Update stock quatity from a product sku
 *
 * @param int $stock_qty The new stock quatity
 * @param int $sku The product sku
 * @return int/null
 */
function update_stock_qty_from_product_sku( $stock_qty, $sku ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm1
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm2
            ON pm1.post_id =  pm2.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_meta_lookup pml
            ON pm1.post_id =  pml.product_id
        SET pm1.meta_value = %d, pml.stock_quantity = %d
        WHERE pm1.meta_key = '_stock'
            AND pm2.meta_key = '_sku'
            AND pm2.meta_value = '%s'
    ", $stock_qty, $stock_qty, $sku ) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Related:** [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server/1293347#1293347)

Comment: @fiter Sorry, I don't have anything better for the moment, but it's quicker than the way you where using… Don't forget that you need also to update `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` table too…

Answer (score 0):

You need first post id then you can update stock value.
First get the post id by sku

```
global $wpdb;
$productId = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );
```

we will get product id then just guess
$productValue = 50; then

```
if ( $product_id )
{
$wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=".$productValue." WHERE post_id=".$productId." AND meta_key=`_stock`" );
}
```

dear try this code it will work